# mysql 5.6.35 DELETE FROM error 1054

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, mysql-error-1054

I am attempting to perform a fairly simple command:

```
DELETE from table WHERE date = date(’2018-07-01’);
```

However, when I run this command on MySQL, I receive the following error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column `’2018` in 'where clause'

Any ideas on what I should be doing here so the query can run? I am using MySQL 5.6.35.

Comment: Probably you have copied the SQL statement from somewhere the qoute looks to be the wrong one.. SQL qoute it should be single qoute like `'`.. Also `date = date(’2018-07-01’)` can be written more simple like `date = '2018-07-01'`

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for reply. I corrected the original error message I was seeing. Even if I take out the date() section, I still get the same error: mysql> DELETE from table
    -> WHERE date = ’2018-07-01’
    -> ;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '’2018' in 'where clause'

Comment: Typo error. voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Strings in SQL are denoted by `'`s. Your code uses `’`s instead. Additionally, if those are your real table and column names, you should escape them:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `date` = DATE('2018-07-01')
```

Comment: `date = DATE('2018-07-01')` can be written more simple `date = '2018-07-01'` @TomJackson like i said in the comments.. (rememeber the backtick escapes ( ` )  stackoverflow format also works with backticks)

Comment: I have faced this issue due to a trigger. When I deleted the Trigger the issue was solved. Can anyone tell me why so happened?